# Node and npm have stopped working

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

> 3130 segmentation fault  node
>
> 3152 segmentation fault  npm

These errors happened after I tried to update node by running `sudo n latest`

Now I can't even uninstall. Please help.

Comment: Try running [the official installer](https://nodejs.org/en/) to overwrite what `n` apparently broke.

Comment: @robertklep That worked!! I don't know why I didn't think of that sooner :P. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some reasons this may have happened;

- You haven't recompiled your native modules after upgrading from your previous version, or
- The native module in question isn't compatible with the more recent v8 (or through NaN)

Comment: Thanks, you're right, there was an error during compilation after the upgrade.